# TXR lisp: processing TXR collected data

Tags: text-processing, txr

I have the following lisp data for which I would like to achieve a specific output. I got this output using `@(do (prinl order) (prinl location) ...)` from my TXR parser.

```
(defvar order '(0 1 2 3 4 5))
(defvar location 
  '("shape" "shape/rectangle" "shape/square" "shape/rectangle" "shape/rectangle" ""))
(defvar headings 
  '(("geometer") ("id" "width: cm" "height: cm") 
    ("id" "length: m") ("id" "width: cm" "height: cm")
    ("angle: °") ("year" "month" "day")))
(defvar values 
  '(("Alice") 
    (("1" "13" "15") ("2" "12" "14"))
    (("1" "10") ("2" "5") ("3..5" "7") 
     ("6;8" "15;12") ("7" "20") ("9..10" "25;30"))
    (("3" "5" "12.2")) ("90") ("2017" "03" "01")))
(defvar type '("meta" "data" "data" "data" "meta" "meta"))
```

At the end of the day, my desired output are CSV tables

```
[shape/rectangle]
year,month,day,geometer,angle: °,id,width: cm,height: cm
2017,03,01,90,Alice,1,13,15
2017,03,01,90,Alice,2,12,14
2017,03,01,90,Alice,3,5,12.2

[shape/square]
year,month,day,geometer,id,length: m
2017,03,01,Alice,1,10
2017,03,01,Alice,2,5
2017,03,01,Alice,3,7
2017,03,01,Alice,4,7
2017,03,01,Alice,5,7
2017,03,01,Alice,6,15
2017,03,01,Alice,8,12
2017,03,01,Alice,7,20
2017,03,01,Alice,9,25
2017,03,01,Alice,10,30
```

I have written some TXR lisp code for decompressing values:

```
(defun str-range-p (x)
  (m^$ #/\d+\.\.\d+/ x))

(defun str-range-expand (x)
  [apply range [mapcar int-str (split-str x "..")]])

(defun str-int-list-p (s)
  (and (str-list-p s)
       (all (str-list-expand s)
            (lambda (x)
              (or (int-str x)
                  (str-range-p x))))))

(defun str-list-p (x)
  (search-str x ";"))

(defun str-list-expand (x)
  (split-str x ";"))

(defun expand (s)
  (cond ((str-int-list-p s)
         (flatten [mapcar (lambda (x)
                            (if (str-range-p x)
                                (str-range-expand x)
                              (int-str x)))
                  (str-list-expand s)]))
        ((str-list-p s) (str-list-expand s))
        ((str-range-p s) (str-range-expand s))
        ((int-str s) (int-str s))
        (t s)))
```

And for checking if a location string is the parent of another location string:

```
(defun level-up (x)
  (cond ((equal x "") nil)
        ((search-str x "/")
         (sub-str x 0 (search-str x "/" 0 t)))
        (t "")))

(defun parent-location-p (x y)
  (or (equal x y)
      (equal x "")
      (and (not (equal y ""))
           (match-str (level-up y) x))))
```

I'm primarily interested in what TXR lisp built-in functions you think might be good for solving the remainder of this task to achieve the desired output. And, how would you approach the existing code differently to take advantage of existing TXR lisp features?

Comment: This question is slightly broad. When I need to do something like this, I use the TXR pattern language for getting the data out, and stuff it into an object model.   Range expansion code is the topic of a Rosetta Code task which has a [TXR solution](https://www.rosettacode.org/wiki/Range_expansion). Also, range *extraction* (converting a list of integers into compressed ranges) is also a Rosetta Code task, with a [TXR solution](https://www.rosettacode.org/wiki/Range_extraction#TXR).

Comment: I agree. Sorry about that. I really appreciate all the support you've given me to get up to speed with TXR. I'll keep at the problem and either delete the question or reduce its scope to a specific question about TXR lisp.

Comment: Thanks, @Kaz. I undeleted the question again in light of your edits if that is fine with you. If you moved that to your own question, I'd accept. Otherwise, I'll delete it again :)

Comment: See if you can improve this. I would give the `table` class a `rows-raw` slot which takes the raw syntax from the parse. Its `:postinit` handler could then do the parsing, with the help of information from `headers`.  The `make-values` function could take two arguments: value syntax, and a `header` object. That could be zippered over with `mapcar`, using the values and headers list. Based on the type information in the header, it could make parsing decisions (like is the field numeric or not), to make that area less hacky.

Comment: I dislike the `(usl slot)` and `(usl method ...)` macros for obtaining higher functions that bind slots and method calls to objects. I'm toying with this idea. Suppose there is a leading dot like `.a.b.c`.  This could expand to `(uref a b c)`. This macro could then produce the higher order function, so we can do `(mapcar .(method arg) obj-list)` or `(mapcar .slot.bar.whatever obj-list)` et cetera. Basically, omit the expression before the leftmost dot and it gets curried, and you get a one-arg function that takes the object.

Comment: That syntax seems pretty intuitive to me, and consistent with the generic sequence procedures.

Comment: I got it done already. With some sleight of hand, I wedged the syntax into the parser without conflicts, and the rest of it was almost trivial. Very easy `uref` macro and just a few lines to handle the pretty printing of `uref` back to the dot notation, sharing some implementation with `qref`.

Comment: Can't wait to use it!

Comment: What you might also like is that the mandatory `-` to scan stdin is going away. No more `cmd | txr myprog.txr -`; just `cmd | txr myprog.txr`.

Comment: That sounds very useful. Will that work if I make a `/usr/bin/txr` script? I'd like it to work both ways as well: either take data from standard input or the file argument, whichever is present. Maybe I can do that already and just haven't it figured it out...

Comment: Yes, a hash bang script will also work more conveniently, because it also won't need that `-` argument any more; it will default to stdin if no files are present.

Comment: I've added a couple of cli options to this script, but using them causes it to get stuck opening the option flags as a data source (as discovered by `@(name src)`. Do you usually handle cli processing with `@(next)` or should I not be expecting that and have another issue with my code?

Comment: You can match through the arguments as if they were lines of a text file with `@(next :args)`. If you use `@(next)` in that context, it will apply to the argument which follows any that have been consumed. I've done some *ad hoc* command line parsing that way though nowadays I'd tend to reach for the `getopts` function (not related to any POSIX thing). A modest example of TXR-based command line parsing occurs in the `txr-embedded-arg.txr` utility in the source tree.

Comment: Yikes; the Command Line Option Processing doc section neglects to describe the `opt` constructor function that it recommends and exemplifies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution works on the sample data given in an earlier edit of the question. It doesn't save the data in different `.csv` files but its output indicates what goes where.

A few objects are used to organize the logic. Locations are represented by the `locations` structure which automatically breaks the path names into components for easy analysis. Headings are represented as `heading` objects, which treat the type notation somewhat; currently it is only used for reformatting the integers representing years, days and months to the proper notation with leading zeros. Tables are represented as `table` objects which hold various properties.  Values, however, are just lists. A table contains a list of rows, and rows are just lists of values. Values are normally scalar. If one or more values in a row are value are lists, that means that the row is a compression of multiple rows (as a result of the `..` and `;` notation). Ranges are expanded using code straight from the Rosetta Code range expansion, adapted to the delimiters used here.

The parser is modified only very slightly. The `:counter` is gone, and the main `collect` has instead a `:vars (tables)`: only a list of tables emerges and these are objects constructed using the `new` macro. Also, there is a new `@(rebind values (values))` so that `meta` tables come out in the same representation: though they have just one row, we want their `rows` property to hold a list of rows, just like `data` tables.

```
@(do
   (defstruct (location str) nil
     str path

     (:method parse (me)
       (set me.path (tok-str me.str #/[^\/]+/)))

     (:method format (me)
       (set me.str `@{me.path "/"}`))

     (:method level-up (me)
       (new location path (butlast me.path)))

     (:method is-prefix-of (me maybe-suffix)
       (let ((mm (mismatch me.path maybe-suffix.path)))
         (or (not mm) (eql mm (length me.path)))))

     (:method print (me stream pretty-p)
       (put-string `@{me.path "/"}` stream))

     (:method equal (me) me.path)

     (:postinit (me)
       (if me.str
         me.(parse)
         me.(format))))

   (defstruct (heading str) nil
     str name type

     (:method parse (me)
       (tree-case (split-str me.str #/: */)
         ((nm ty) (set me.name nm me.type ty))
         ((nm)    (set me.name nm me.type nm))))

     (:method format-value (me arg)
       (casequal me.type
         ("year" (fmt "~,04d" arg))
         (("month" "day") (fmt "~,02d" arg))
         (t (if (stringp arg)
              arg
              (tostringp arg)))))

     (:method print (me stream pretty-p)
       (put-string (or me.str
                       (if (equal me.name me.type)
                         `@{me.name}`
                         `@{me.name}: @{me.type}`))
                   stream))

     (:postinit (me)
       (when me.str
         me.(parse))))

  (defun expand-helper (list)
     (cond
       ((null list) nil)
       ((consp (first list))
        (append (range (first (first list))
                       (second (first list)))
                (rangeexpand (rest list))))
       (t (cons (first list) (rangeexpand (rest list))))))

   (defun rangeexpand (list)
     (uniq (expand-helper list)))

   (defun make-values (string)
     (if [#/\.\.|;/ string]
       (let ((syntax (collect-each ((p (split-str string ";")))
                       (tree-case (split-str p "..")
                         ((from to . junk)
                          ;; if junk isn't nil, error!
                          (list (num-str from) (num-str to)))
                         ((single . junk)
                          (num-str single))))))
         (rangeexpand syntax))
       (or (num-str string) string)))

   (defstruct table nil
     location headings rows type order
     (:static order-cnt 0)

     (:method merge (me other)
       (new table
            location other.location
            headings (append me.headings other.headings)
            type other.type
            rows (append-each ((mr me.rows))
                   (collect-each ((or other.rows))
                     (append mr or)))
            order other.order))

     (:method cat (me other)
       (let ((me-copy (copy-struct me)))
         (set me-copy.rows (append me.rows other.rows))
         me-copy))

     (:method expand-rows (me)
       (labels ((expand-row (row)
                  (build
                    (if [find-if consp row]
                      (while* [find-if consp row]
                        (let ((this (mapcar [iffi consp car] row))
                              (next (mapcar [iffi consp cdr] row)))
                          (add this)
                          (set row next)))
                      (add row)))))
         [mappend expand-row me.rows]))

     (:postinit (me)
       (unless me.order
         (set me.order (inc me.order-cnt))))))
@(define os)@/[ ]*/@(end)
@(define location)@\
@  (cases)@\
@/[a-z]+/@(eol)@\
@  (or)@\
@/[a-z]+//@(location)@\
@  (end)@\
@(end)
@(define heading)@/[a-z]+(:[^,]*)?/@(end)
@(define value)@/[^,]+/@(end)
@(define table (location headings values type))
@  (cases)
@    (cases)@\
[[@location]]@(or)[[]]@(bind location "")@\
@    (end)
@    (coll)@(os)@{headings (heading)}@(os)@(end)
@    (coll)@(os)@{values (value)}@(os)@(end)
@    (rebind values (values))
@    (bind type "meta")
@(os)
@  (or)
[@location]
@    (coll)@(os)@{headings (heading)}@(os)@(end)
@    (collect :gap 0)
@      (coll)@(os)@{values (value)}@(os)@(end)
@    (until)
@      (os)
@    (end)
@    (bind type "data")
@  (end)
@(end)
@(collect :vars (tables))
@  (table location headings values type)
@  (bind tables @(new table
                      location (new (location location))
                      headings (mapcar (do new (heading @1)) headings)
                      rows (mapcar (op mapcar make-values) values)
                      type type))
@(until)
@  (eof)
@(end)
@(do
   (let* ((metas (keepqual "meta" tables (usl type)))
          (datas (remqual "meta" tables (usl type)))
          (sorted-metas [sort (copy metas) > (op length @1.location.path)])
          (combined-datas (hash-values (group-reduce (hash :equal-based)
                                                     (usl location)
                                                     (do if @1 @1.(cat @2) @2)
                                                     datas)))
          (augmented-datas (collect-each ((d combined-datas))
                             (each ((m sorted-metas))
                               (when m.location.(is-prefix-of d.location)
                                 (set d m.(merge d))))
                             d)))
     (each ((a augmented-datas))
       (put-line `@{a.location}.csv:`)
       (put-line `@{a.headings ","}`)
       (each ((r a.(expand-rows)))
         (put-line `@{(mapcar (ret @1.(format-value @2))
                              a.headings r) ","}`))
       (put-line))))
```

The requirement for catenating tables with the same location is handled using the `group-reduce` expression which relies on a hash table to identify like items and combine them using the `table` structure's `cat` method. A table catenates another table by producing a copy of itself with the `rows` replaced by appending its original `rows` with that of the other one.

Merging the additional properties from meta tables is performed by iterating over all of the data tables and applying the matching properties. For each data table, we iterate all of the meta tables in order of decreasing path length (most particular to least). From each meta table whose location is a prefix of the data table's location, we merge on the properties with the `table` `merge` method. (This also works functionally, like `cat`: it returns a new, merged table). Merge means that we stick on all the headings from the meta table, and do a cross-producting operation on the rows: each new meta row on the left is paired with every row of the table being extended on the right.

Expanding rows which contain multiple values is done by `table` `expand-rows`. This simply makes a copy of each row, with each list substituted by its first item (the Lisp `car`). It then iterates over the `cdr`: a new row is calculated where the lists are replaced by their `cdr`.  This repeats, until the lists are exhausted. For instance `(1 (a b) 3 (x y))` will produce `(1 a 3 x)`, with a "remainder" of `(1 (b) 3 (y))`. This remainder produces `(1 b 3 y)` with a new  remainder of `(1 nil 3 nil)`. This doesn't contain any more `consp` values (all are `atom`) so the iteration terminates.

Comment: Oops; the `location`  struct's `print` method should use `me.(format)` rather than contaiing a redundant formatting expression. :)

Comment: I'm a little confused how the `(from to . junk)` and `(single . junk)` forms work in `make-values`. It makes sense to me that it would help with things like taking "1..5..7..8" to `(1 5 . (7 8))`, but I would be more worried about getting non-numeric values after which I'd like to fail.

Comment: Playing around with `num-str` I know it will extract the prefixed number even if there are trailing alphanumeric characters. However, I could imagine wanting to generalize ranges to also handling alphabetical ranges as well (e.g. "A..Z")

Comment: @wdkrnls Yes, you discovered the dirty little hack I did there: just calling `num-str` and ignoring the trailing junk.